# O que é UML? Para que serve?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, uml, projeto-de-software, documentação, gerenciamento-de-projetos

Uma questão conceitual.

- O que é UML?
- Para que serve?
- Ela é realmente útil? Portanto, devemos aprender?
- É amplamente adotada?
- Quais defeitos dessa linguagem?
- É ligada com orientação a objetos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UML ou Unified Modeling Language, como o nome diz é uma linguagem de modelagem, ou seja, ela deve descrever como um modelo de um domínio deve ser.

Ela foi padronizada pelo Object Management Group ([OMG](https://www.omg.org/)) para ser usada universalmente em vez de diversas outras formas separadas e muitas vezes concorrentes entre si, o que criava problema de comunicação porque as pessoas não falavam a mesma língua, você tinha que aprender uma forma nova se entrasse em um projeto que adotou uma forma diferente do que estava acostumado.

Ela permite documentar diversas formas e fases do desenvolvimento de um software enquanto se trata do modelo (é possível ir um pouco além).

Com ela é possível criar diagramas para demonstrar vários aspectos do que o software tem, tais como:

- **Estrutura** (componente, classe, implantação, objeto, pacote, perfil, composição)

[image: Diagrama de classes]

- **Comportamento** (atividade, caso de uso, máquina de estado, temporizador)

[image: Diagrama de caso de uso]

- **Interação** (sequência, comunicação, resumo de interação) muitas vezes eles são considerados de comportamento

[image: Diagrama de sequência]

[Exemplos de diagramas](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/).

Um dos trunfos propagados é que os diagramas podem ser executados e dá pra ver como fica realmente aquilo que se modelou, e até é possível gerar o código fonte para algumas linguagens de programação e teoricamente não precisaria programar nada, essa linguagem seria universal. Claro que depende da implementação.

Isso pelo menos é a teoria. Na prática gera código muito ruins, desconsidera porque existem tantas linguagens e acha que é só sintaxe diferente. Portanto a ideia é errada.

## Utilidade e defeitos

A ideia não é tão errada quando tenta fornecer uma forma única de demonstrar como a solução é montada, mas existem diagramas demais, alguns com detalhes demais, outros que faltam certas coisas para ser tão completo quanto ele se dispõe a ser, e é comum ser bem complicado para pouco benefício em certos casos.
Ele burocratiza o desenvolvimento, o que pode ser bom em alguns casos, mas ruim em outros. Curiosamente alguns proponentes de metodologias chamadas de ágeis defendem o uso deste mecanismo, o que vai contra a ideia original de Agile.

Algumas organização não vivem sem, algumas abusam, outras usam onde realmente ajuda dar uma clareza para o que se está fazendo.

Se usar no que realmente é útil pode ajudar pontualmente para planejar e visualizar melhor o que está fazendo, e com isso pode dar ideias para melhorar o *design* e quem sabe facilitar a execução do projeto.
Um dos problemas dele é a distância na terminologia e forma de trabalhar com certos aspectos que é muito diferente das linguagens que as pessoas efetivamente usam.

Ela é responsável, por exemplo, por fazer as pessoas chamarem campo de atributo. As pessoas nem sabem disso.

Embora seja possível fazer com papel e caneta quase todo mundo usa algum software para criar isto.
Há controvérsias sobre seu uso. Há quem não viva sem, mas a maioria das pessoas não usam. Minha experiência é que não é o uso ou não uso dele que faz o softwares serem melhores.
O uso consciente, pontual, de acordo com o contexto, quando há motivação real, e não seguindo uma regra de fazer tudo sempre, pode ser útil.

Lembre-se que sempre que tiver a mesma informação em dois lugares diferentes viola o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) (neste caso do projeto como um todo) e causa problema. Então para usar isso como uma coisa que rege todo ciclo do desenvolvimento, em oposição a usar para entender melhor algo antes de fazer, ou seja, se ele não for usado como documentação, pode se tornar um problema. Você muda o código e não muda a documentação, já era.

Por isso ele foi pensado realmente para substituir o codificação, o que na prática "nunca" é feito.
Na forma como UML foi pensado, não costuma ser uma boa e vai contra a forma moderna de desenvolvimento de software. Para usar os diagramas individuais quando necessário para ajudar o entendimento é ok. Porém usar desta firma não está usando UML de fato. Pior que usar, é dizer que usa e nem saber que não está usando. Um monte de organização faz de conta que usa.

Pesquisando um pouco sobre o assunto para responder eu percebo que muita gente tem opiniões positivas quando argumentam de forma errada sobre, ou não conseguem sustentar o que falam, são só opiniões.

Cada vez mais tem pessoas aceitando o fato que é uma perda de tempo.

Se alguém quer que se use algo, deve provar que aquilo é bom. Não devemos adotar algo sem a certeza de que traz mais benefícios que malefícios/custo.

## Conclusão

Tende a ser usada com OOP, mas em parte dá para usar em qualquer paradigma.

Para *brainstorming* é bom, para documentação pode ser útil aqui e ali, mas pra guiar todo o projeto é uma insanidade.

[Da minha resposta no Quora](https://pt.quora.com/O-que-%C3%A9-a-UML/answer/Antonio-Maniero).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).