# UML e BPMN são iguais?

Tags: modelagem, engenharia-de-software

**no desenvolvimento de software a UML e a BPMN podem ser utilizadas da mesma forma e com a mesma  finalidade no processo de modelagem?**

Comment: BPMN se assemelha ao diagrama de atividades que é apenas um dos diagramas que compões o UML. Veja [O que é UML? Para que serve?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/507604/137387)

Answer (score -1):

A linguagem de modelagem unificada (UML) adota uma abordagem orientada a objetos para a modelagem de software, enquanto a BPMN adota uma abordagem orientada para o processo de negócios

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).